# Python - urllib2 > how to escape HTTP errors

Tags: python, urllib2

I am making a python app and I want to read a file from the net.
this is the code that I am using to read it :

```
urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com/check.txt").read()
```

everything works great but when I point it to a url that do not exist, it gives HTTP 404: not found error and that is normal.

the problem is that the app is designed to work on windows, so, it will be compiled.
on windows, when the app tries to get a file from a url that do not exist, the app crushes and gives an error window + it creates a log that contains HTTP 404: NOT found error.

I tried to escape this error but I failed. This is the full code:

```
import urllib2

file = urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com/check.txt")

try:
    file.read()
except urllib2.URLError:
    print "File Not Found"

else:
    print "File is found"
```

please, if you know how to escape this error, help me.

Comment: The error occurs on `urllib.urlopen(...)` (which is *outside* your `try`) **not** on `file.read()` (which is never reached).

Comment: put `urllib2.urlopen(...)` inside try

Comment: Thank you brothers for your help. I could solve it now by trying the solution that @karthikr provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply the try..except around the urlopen, not the read.

Try this

```
import urllib2
try:
    fh = urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com/check.txt')
    print fh.read()
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print e.code 
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print e.code
```